Rails 7 action_text not working. Toolbar and content are not displayed and visible
My action_text toolbar and my content is not displayed. My content is in hidden form.action text editor not clickable and toolbar not visible.
Last week, all working. I have change cloudinary to S3 but i don't know if there a link between.
Please if you have solution

I found a solution with <%= javascript_include_tag 'trix' %>.
Importmap in rails 7 seems to be a problem.

I had the same issue, turned out I hadn't run
rails action_text:install

Could you try that type of errors:

Check the JavaScript Console Errors on browser specific.

Re-compile your assets: rails assets:precompile.

Ensure Active Storage, Trix, and ActionText JS are properly included


require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

